# How to remove focus from the left and right carousel arrows after clicking on them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-carousel

It is a very interesting issue.

In the below image, there are left and right carousel arrows. There is a text box under each item where the user can type the name. If the user clicks on either left or the right arrow, and then, if he clicks on any input text box and clicks left, then the control still remains on the left and right arrows. I cannot go left on the input text box.

I hope I have tried explaining the issue. I cannot get the control of the textbox once I click the left/right arrow. I cannot show you the code because of company's policy. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so this looks like an issue created by the carousel you are using, some carousels have implemented that wherever you click inside the carousel it will actually take it as if you are clicking the left or right arrow depending on which section of the carousel you click.

Without looking at the code Im thinking you would have to overwrite the onclick function or use a carousel that doesn't handles the feature I mentioned above.